# Using Postman Environments

Tags: windows, postman

I am trying to code my tests using Postman, but I am having some difficulty in understanding how to use `pm.environments.set` and `pm.environments.get`.

My code:

### Collection 1

```js
var a = 0;

if (test = 100)
    {
        a++;
    }

pm.environments.set("1-100",a);
```

### Collection 2

```js
var b = 0;

if (test = 100)
    {
        b++;
    }

pm.environments.set("1-200",b);
```

So this has worked and recorded the two collections, but how do I put this into a sum for the end collection (3)?

### Collection 3

```js
console.log("Number of items: " + {{1-100}} + {{1-200}})
```

I am looking at the documentation about [Postman Setting and Getting variables](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman-sandbox/), but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's OK now, I am using `parseFloat` and is working.

```js
parseFloat(pm.globals.get("1-100") + pm.globals.get("2-100"));
```

Changing the `pm.environments` to `pm.globals` also worked out better, so that I can use the variables between my collections.